# Blank Page on Redirect View

Tags: java, spring, controller

I've bumped into a strange problem.

I have a Spring Controller. Inside it I check for a particular condition and if true I execute a redirect to another controller like this:

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView(url));
```

The problem is that a blank page is being displayed. Very strangely then, when I view the source of the blank page, I see all the HTML there.

Any ideas, what's wrong please?

Comment: Is the page even blank if you request it directly (without redirect)?

Comment: Does viewing the source of the page trigger a new request of the page? Depending on the browser and the cache headers, viewing the source might cause the browser to go load the page again — in that case what you see might in the browser might be a first, empty response; and what you see in view source is a second, complete response.

Comment: @Ralph If it's requested directly, it shows

Comment: do you have some fancy http header functionality?

Comment: You should accept more answers. You're rate is very low for all the questions you've asked.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure there are no javascript exceptions.

In some webpages, javascript may be used to show the body or div only after the page has loaded all data.
If there is a javascript exception, it might stop execution and the call to show the body/div may never get executed.

There may be other reasons in your case, but this does happen once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Might be an ovbvious answer but check your logs for any exceptions.  I had a page do something similiar to this only to realize that I caught some error but did not display it on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be your status code on redirect is not 200, please confirm from your "browser" console/network

you can check your code as well if you are deliberately setting HTTP status code to 201 or any other.